# How to know the radius from This SVG?

Tags: svg

I have two SVG Paths  , Please how to calculate the radius for each one .
From SVG experts please tell me is there any difference between them ?

```css
<style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .str0 {stroke:#2B2A29;stroke-width:0.762}
    .fil0 {fill:red}
   ]]>
  </style>
```

```html
<h1>SVG Path Circle</h1>

<div>
    Circle 1
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      
        <path class="fil0 str0" d="M50 50l0 0c0,4 -3,7 -7,7l0 0c-4,0 -7,-3 -7,-7l0 0c0,-4 3,-7 7,-7l0 0c4,0 7,3 7,7z"
              />
    </svg>
    Circle 2
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      
        <path class="fil0 str0" d="M50 50l0 0c-5,0 -8,4 -8,8l0 0c0,5 3,8 8,8l0 0c4,0 8,-3 8,-8l0 0c0,-4 -4,-8 -8,-8z"/>
  
    </svg>
</div>
```

---

How this rule is applied on my circles.

`path d="
        M cx, cy
        m -r, 0
        a r,r 0 1,0 (r * 2),0
        a r,r 0 1,0 -(r * 2),0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of a circle is its width divided by 2.

```js
alert("radius 1 = " + document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].getBBox().width / 2 + "\nradius 2 = " + document.getElementsByTagName("path")[1].getBBox().width / 2)
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .str0 {stroke:#2B2A29;stroke-width:0.762}
    .fil0 {fill:red}
   ]]>
  </style>
```

```html
<h1>SVG Path Circle</h1>

<div>
    Circle 1
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      
        <path class="fil0 str0" d="M50 50l0 0c0,4 -3,7 -7,7l0 0c-4,0 -7,-3 -7,-7l0 0c0,-4 3,-7 7,-7l0 0c4,0 7,3 7,7z"
              />
    </svg>
    Circle 2
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      
        <path class="fil0 str0" d="M50 50l0 0c-5,0 -8,4 -8,8l0 0c0,5 3,8 8,8l0 0c4,0 8,-3 8,-8l0 0c0,-4 -4,-8 -8,-8z"/>
  
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Many Regards for you , Please can you explain how the circle rule that I wrote above applied on my path !

Comment: It doesn't apply at all, your path is drawn using different commands.